# XML separating a list of elements with a comma

Tags: xml, xslt

I was wondering if it would be possible to separate a list of items (in my case, these would be grades) by a comma, and have the last one separated by an 'and' instead.

E.g. `Maths:A (GCSE), English:B (GCSE) and Science:A (GCSE)`

Mine currently outputs like this:
`Maths:A (GCSE)English:B (GCSE)Science:A (GCSE)`

I think the issue with my code is that when using the `position()` function, it isn't taking the correct node's position (although I could be wrong!)

XML Code:

```
<assignment>
    <education>
        <qualifications>
                <qual>Maths</qual>      <grade>A</grade>    <level>GCSE</level>
                <qual>English</qual>    <grade>B</grade>    <level>GCSE</level>
                <qual>Science</qual>    <grade>A</grade>    <level>GCSE</level>
            </qualifications>
    </education>
</assignment>
```

XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="education">
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

This obviously doesn't incorporate separating the last two elements by using an 'and'; I have not been able to find anything that would help accomplish this.

Comment: This is not valid XSLT - only `<xsl:sort>` and `<xsl:with-param>` are valid inside `<xsl:apply-templates>`

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

the node education is always the last node (its the only one ;-) )

you are looking for the the last 'qual' element

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="education">
```

should be

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="qual">
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Doing this seems to stop it from displaying anything; however even if it was displaying, surely it could only display the subject name as that is the only information inside of the 'qual' tags?

Comment: I thought you just had a problem with the position ...
I put a simple solution in another answer

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 1.0, I'd match each `qual` and then output the first `grade` and `level` siblings.

You can test for preceding/following `qual` siblings to determine the separator.

Example...

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="qual">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::qual and following-sibling::qual">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::qual">
                <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,':',
            following-sibling::grade[1],
            concat(' (',following-sibling::level,')'))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Maths:A (GCSE), English:B (GCSE) and Science:A (GCSE)
```

---

If you were using XSLT 2.0, I'd use an `xsl:for-each-group` and separate templates to override `grade` and `level`.

Example... (produces the same output as the XSLT 1.0 version)

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="qualifications">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="qual">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(position()=1) and not(position()=last())">
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
                    <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="qual">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,':')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="level">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' (',.,')')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This looks promising; I am not currently able to adapt this to my code, however I will comment with what happens when I get the chance. I am unfortunately not able to use XSLT 2.0 as I need to run it through a browser (most likely to be IE, Firefox or Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="qual[last()]">
    <xsl:text> and </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="qual[1]">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="qual">
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="grade">
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="level">
    <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What is the result you get with this?

Comment: MathsA (GCSE),EnglishB (GCSE),ScienceA (GCSE)
I forgot an <xsl:text>: </xsl:text> in front of the grade

Comment: So where is the required " and " that is the basis of this question?

Comment: Thanks you're right - cut 'n' paste is not as easy as xslt ;-)
here is the real solution i fixed the missing ':' as well

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply say exactly what you want:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="assignment/education/qualifications/qual">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last() - 1">
            <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input:

```
<assignment>
   <education>
      <qualifications>
         <qual>Maths</qual>
         <grade>A</grade>
         <level>GCSE</level>
         <qual>English</qual>
         <grade>B</grade>
         <level>GCSE</level>
         <qual>Science</qual>
         <grade>A</grade>
         <level>GCSE</level>
      </qualifications>
   </education>
</assignment>
```

the result is:

```
Maths, English and Science
```

Adding the grade and level values is left as a (trivial) exercise for the reader.